# Bash Script to Create Multiple Tmux Sessions and Windows in Each Session

Tags: bash, tmux

I have several directories that I work with at work and if I restart my machine I do not have to setup tmux sessions and windows for each of those directories. Each tmux session, I want 3 windows with names as follows, `() => {}`, `Tests`, `Git`. So I have started to create a script that creates a session and names the first window just fine. But how do I create the other windows?

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

tmux new-session -ds Project1 -c ~/Development/project1 -n "() => {}"
tmux new-session -ds Project2 -c ~/Development/project2 -n "() => {}"
tmux new-session -ds Components -c ~/Development/components -n "() => {}"
tmux new-session -ds dotfiles -c ~/.dotfiles -n "() => {}"
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
# create session in detached mode and create a new window in it
tmux new-session -ds Project1  -n "() => {}" -c ~/Development/project1

# create other windows
tmux new-window  -t  Project1: -n Tests
tmux new-window  -t  Project1: -n Git
```